# slip rate dependent friction - hyphen needed?

Tags: hyphenation

Should I put a hyphen for friction that depends on slip rate?

Possibilities:

> slip rate-dependent friction

or

> slip-rate dependent friction

or

> slip rate dependent friction

The last one seems to be most widely used, however, I have also seen the first and the second in a few papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Open compounds** like "slip rate" should be used in compound adjectives with an **en dash**:

> slip rate–dependent friction.

Chicago Manual of Style, quoted from [here](http://grammarpartyblog.com/2011/08/30/simply-dashing-part-two-the-en-dash/):

> *The en dash can be used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of its elements consists of an open compound or when both elements consist of hyphenated compounds.*

Comment: I don't think so.  "slip-rate" is a compound.  But dependent friction **is not** a compound.  What we have here is a compound (slip-rate) with some more sentence after it, no?  (Nevertheless, a fabulous reference and a great piece of info.)

Comment: "Slip rate" is an open compound, and is being hyphenated with "dependent" to form an adjective. (Disclaimer: I'm not a linguist)

Comment: hmm good point...

Answer (score -1):

As a rule of thumb, think of the possible confusion. Is it a slip that is rate dependent or is the friction dependent on the slip rate. Clearly the latter. Therefore: slip-rate dependent.
("hyphen" and "dash" are synonymous. "en dash" doesn't exist.)

Comment: If the en dash does not exist, why is it in the Chicago Manual of Style?

Comment: The comment that an en dash does not exist is flamboyantly mad, so we all love that :)  But I agree completely that "slip-rate" (likely) needs to be clearly demarcated as a "unit".